# Powershell New-ScheduledTaskTrigger recurring task with -RepetitionInterval

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, eventtrigger

I'm finding the errors related to ScheduledTask cmdles give extremely cryptic errors. 
I want to schedule a test task to run every 1 minute and repeat forever.
Here's what I'm trying, but no success:

```
cls
#$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "e:\Scripts\TestClusteredTask.cmd"
$DurationTimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1 
$DurationTimeSpanIndefinite = ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue) 
$DurationTempTest = New-TimeSpan -Days 1000
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At "00:01" -RepetitionInterval $DurationTimeSpan -RepetitionDuration $DurationTempTest
```

also tried this:

```
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At "00:01" -RepetitionInterval $DurationTimeSpan -RepeatIndefinitely
```

Error Output:

```
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Users\nwalters\Documents\AddTestClusteredTask.ps1:6 char:12
+ $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At "00:01" -RepetitionInterval $Dura ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,New-ScheduledTaskTrigger
```

I'm referencing this web page for instructions. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849759.aspx

Powerhsell Version 4 on Win 2012/R2

Comment: I think you need to specify `-DaysInterval` when you use `Daily`. Look at `Parameter Set: Daily` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821.aspx). `-DaysInterval 1` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [tech net](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821.aspx) this is the dataset you are using

```
Parameter Set: Daily
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger [-Daily] -At <DateTime> [-DaysInterval <Int32> ] [-RandomDelay <TimeSpan> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

In your examples you are specifying `-RepetitionInterval` and `-RepetitionDuration` which are part of the `-Once` parameter set.

```
Parameter Set: Once
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger [-Once] -At <DateTime> [-RandomDelay <TimeSpan> ] [-RepetitionDuration <TimeSpan> ] [-RepetitionInterval <TimeSpan> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

That is why you are getting an ambiguity error. It does not know which parameter set you are using.

```
FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,New-ScheduledTaskTrigger
```

So you need to specify `-Once` if you want to use those other parameters.

Comment: Did you actually run that?  Gives same error for me. Based on the syntax, what is considered a "CommonParameter"?  If I specify -Daily, seems like -RepetitionInterval and -RepetitionDuration both are not accepted, but they are accepted with the -Once parm.

I'm using ClusteredScheduledTasks, so cannot use the Task Scheduler GUI.  But in the GUI, you can select the "Daily" radio button, along with "Repeat task every " then select for example 10 minutes, for a duration of "1 day".

Comment: No I am not able to run that as I don't have powershell 4.0 in front of me. My assumption was based on the technet article. I will pull out a windows 8 machine and see what i can do. Also, it would not be the first time the GUI has done me a favour wherein the complete command is hidden.

Comment: I'm not sure it's different in 3.0.

Comment: This variation works okay: $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -once  -At "00:01" -RepetitionInterval $DurationTimeSpan -RepetitionDuration $$DurationTempTest I'm just don't trust it to start running after a machine restart.

Comment: Powershell 3.0 doesnt support that cmdlet. Also im an idiot and didnt read my own answer. You cannot user `-Daily` and `-Repetition `. I updated my answer to make more sense as it was misleading.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  So if I specify -once, then do I need to add a second trigger to handle the machine restart?  I want to run the task every x minutes all day every day.

Comment: You should be able to test to know for sure but i see not reason why it would not. As long as it gets registered it should follow the `-At` you specify and with the repeating pattern.

Answer (score 18):

I found out that you can modify the Trigger before you link it to the task.
My Script generates a Task with a Trigger at 8:00 o Clock, every day. The tasks is repeaded every 60 Minutes (1 hour) with a random delay of 30 minutes:

```
$Prog = $env:systemroot + "\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$Opt = "-nologo -noninteractive -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy BYPASS -file \\mydomain.local\NETLOGON\Monitoring\monitoring.ps1"
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $Prog -Argument $Opt 
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -DaysInterval 1 -RandomDelay "00:30" -At "08:00"
$Trigger.Repetition = $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -RandomDelay "00:30" -At "08:00" -RepetitionDuration "12:00" -RepetitionInterval "01:00").Repetition
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$Task = Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Principal $Principal -TaskName "Monitor-PS1-V001" -Description "Starts Monitoring-Script" -Force
```

I googled around and found no nice solution.
Hopefully somebody can use my "idea"

Greetings
Robert

Comment: Excellent solution, to the top with you!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I was struggling for hours before I find this.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that you can do this in multiple steps e.g:

```
$ST_A = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "E:\Scheduled Tasks\pause.cmd"
$ST_T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 0am
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Pause_with_asJob2" -Action $ST_A –Trigger $ST_T
Disable-ScheduledTask -Taskname "Pause_with_asJob2"
$ST_T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 03:00 -RepetitionDuration (new-timespan -hour 15) -RepetitionInterval (new-timespan -minutes 15)
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Pause_with_asJob2" -Action $ST_A –Trigger $ST_T
$ST_T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 03:00
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Pause_with_asJob2" -Action $ST_A –Trigger $ST_T
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help someone !!

```
$script="restart_Service"
$trigger=New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 3:00PM
$action=New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute C:\temp\restart.ps1
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -TaskName $script -Description "to restart the service"  -RunLevel Highest -Trigger $trigger
$Task.Triggers.Repetition.Duration = "P1D" 
$Task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = "PT30M"
$Task | Set-ScheduledTask -User "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "restart_Service"
$Task.Triggers.Repetition | fl *
```